# Python: Uploading files FTP_TLS- "550 The parameter is incorrect"

Tags: python, ftp

I'm trying to connect to an FTP server using TLS and upload a text file. The below code connects to the site just fine, but it's not uploading the file. Instead I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:/HR & IT/Ryan/Python Scripts/ftps_connection_test.py", line 16, in <module>
    ftps.storlines("STOR " + filename, open(filename,"r"))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\ftplib.py", line 816, in storlines
    with self.transfercmd(cmd) as conn:
  File "C:\Python33\lib\ftplib.py", line 391, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "C:\Python33\lib\ftplib.py", line 756, in ntransfercmd
    conn, size = FTP.ntransfercmd(self, cmd, rest)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\ftplib.py", line 357, in ntransfercmd
    resp = self.sendcmd(cmd)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\ftplib.py", line 264, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\ftplib.py", line 238, in getresp
    raise error_perm(resp)
ftplib.error_perm: 550 The parameter is incorrect.
```

There's probably something really basic I'm missing, my code is below and any help is much appreciated.

```
import os
from ftplib import FTP_TLS as f

# Open secure connection
ftps = f("ftp.foo.com")
ftps.login(username,password)  
ftps.prot_p()                        

# Create the test txt file to upload 
filename = r"c:\path\to\file"
testFile = open(filename,"w")
testFile.write("Test file with test text")
testFile.close()

# Transfer testFile
ftps.storlines("STOR " + filename, open(filename,"r"))

# Quit connection
ftps.quit()
```

Comment: You should probably ask about the timeout in a new question. Are you able to successfully upload a file using a standalone FTP client?

Comment: Yes I am- I've discovered an answer to my new question on another thread, but the solution there isn't quite working for me. I'll amend this question to remove the timeout bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filename = r"c:\path\to\file"
```

is the *absolute* path to a local file. This same value is being passed in the `STOR` command, i.e.

```
ftps.storlines("STOR " + filename, open(filename,"r"))
```

attempts to perform a `STOR c:\path\to\file` operation, however, it is unlikely that the path exists on the remote server, and the `ftplib.error_perm` exception would suggest that you don't have *permission* to write there (even if it does exist).

You could try this instead:

```
ftps.storlines("STOR " + os.path.basename(filename), open(filename,"r"))
```

which would issue a `STOR file` operation and upload the file to the default directory on the remote server. If you need to upload to a different path on the remote server, just add that to STOR.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks- this seems to have fixed the original issue. I have amended my question with the new code, but having another issue now where it times out.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same error when trying to write upload a file to FTP server. In my case, the destination file name is not the correct format. It was something like
`data_20180411T12:00:12.3435Z.txt`

I renamed something like 
`data_20180411T120012_3435Z.txt`. Then it worked.